# How to get products relational array in loop laravel

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, object

Hello I am having table called `orders`, `order_details`, `product` where `order` contains order data, `order_details` contains product key as foreign key for order items and `product` table has product information.

This is query I am using:

```
$OrderDetails = OrderDetails::where('order_id',$order_id)->with('Product')->get();
```

Following is `order_details` table,

[image]

and I am getting output like this:

[image]

How to get only product details through loops in laavel blade?

Comment: you can do a foreach in $OrderDetails or simply use $OrderDetails->toArray() to check attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OrderDetails is your pivot table.
You can define many-to-many relationships in your model.

In your Product model:

```
public function orders()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class);
}
```

In your Order model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

This way you can get a collection of all related products immediately from your order:

```
$products = $order->products;
```

Comment: While OP seems to have set the relationships, I do think you are trying to suggest a better way to query it, but I think it would be good to indicate the importance of `withPivot` to get access to the other attributes like `qty`, `weight`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Pit this In your order model

```
public function order_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Orderdetail::class);
 }
```

Put this in your order details model

```
  public function order_detail()
   {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
  }
public function product()
      {
           return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
     }
```

Now in you contoller you can get the products info like these

```
$order=order::find($id) ;
foreach ($order->order_details as $detail)
{
$products [] =$detail->product - >name;
}
dd($products)
```